# what is the difference in expect between "send command" and "send -- command"

Tags: tcl, expect

I see some examples where the send command is sent with something like just `send "echo test"` and other places where I see the `send` follow by `--`.  What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`send --` is used to send strings which start with `-` in case it may be interpreted as `send`'s options.

From the [manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html):

> The `--` flag forces the next argument to be interpreted as a string rather than a flag.  **Any  string  can be preceded by `--` whether or not it actually looks like a flag**.  This provides a reliable mechanism to specify variable strings without being tripped up by those that  accidentally  look  like  flags.   (All strings starting with `-` are reserved for future options.)